# Liip Imagine ProxyResolver - how to remove bucket prefix

Tags: symfony, symfony4, liipimaginebundle

```
app.imagine.cache.resolver.proxy:
        class: Liip\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Cache\Resolver\ProxyResolver
        arguments:
            - "@app.imagine.cache.resolver.s3"
            - [ '%env(S3_CDN_URL)%' ]
        tags:
            - { name: "liip_imagine.cache.resolver", resolver: "proxy" }
app.s3:
        class: Aws\S3\S3Client
        factory: [Aws\S3\S3Client, factory]
        arguments:
            -
                version: 'latest'
                region: 'fra1'
                endpoint: '%env(S3_BASE_URL)%'
                credentials:
                    key: '%env(S3_KEY)%'
                    secret: '%env(S3_SECRET_KEY)%'
app.imagine.cache.resolver.s3:
        class: Liip\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Cache\Resolver\AwsS3Resolver
        arguments:
            - "@app.s3"
            - '%env(S3_BUCKET_NAME)%'
        tags:
            - { name: "liip_imagine.cache.resolver", resolver: "s3" }
```

The problem is I'd like to use DigitalOcean spaces CDN and its CDN is per bucket, so there is no bucket prefix.

In the end I get a resolved url like:

```
S3_CDN_URL/bucketName/filePath
```

which is non existent.

I need to get:

```
S3_CDN_URL/filePath
```

I can't find any setting for that.

Basically, I need to access S3 in 'Virtual Hosted Style': https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#access-bucket-intro

Comment: this reads so much as if you want to (mis)use an s3 library for non-s3 stuff.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. Keep it up!

Comment: It appears all this happens automatically and in my case did not work, because of some peculiar bucket naming issue. So, for anyone who's having trouble with this when using Digital Ocean - don't use period in your bucket name.